# Swagger respond with associated objects

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, api-design, openapi

I'm using SwaggerHub with OpenAPI 3 to define an API. One route `GET /foo/{id]`, should return the `foo` object of a given `id`, with its associated `bar` objects. The API will return something like: `{id: 4, name: 'test', bars: [{id: 53, name: 'barName1'}, {id: 87, name: 'barName2'}]}`. I.e. there is a many-to-many relationship between `foo` and `bar`.

How do I describe this in OpenAPI 3 syntax? I have tried using the [`anyOf`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/#anyof-oneof) property. So far I have:

```
paths:
  /foo/{id}:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items: 
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
                anyOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Bar'
```

But this doesn't appear to show the correct schema in the UI (there is no mention of `Bar` in the UI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `anyOf`. `anyOf` indicates an alternative ("either Foo or Bar"), whereas you have a usual nested structure - an object `Foo` with the property `bars` that is an array of `Bar`s. This can be described as:

```yaml
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'

components:
  schemas:
    Foo:
      type: object
      properties:
        bars:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Bar'
      required:
        - bars
    Bar:
      ...
```